# Define 'break' as 'torsk'

Tags: c++, typedef, c-preprocessor

Is is possible to redefine 'break' in such a way that I can just write 'torsk' instead? E.g:

```
switch (chocolateistasty) {

    case true: {
        cout << "It is!" << endl;
        torsk;
    }
    case false: {
        cout << "Nope." << endl;
        torsk;
    }
}
```

I imagine this would be done with some preprocessor commands.

Comment: I'm curious. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Interesting definition of hilarious. If you're looking for mayhem and you're not worried about losing your job over it, might I suggest the following: `#define false true`.

Comment: According to Wiktionary _torsk_ is the Swedish word for someone who visits prostitutes. How utterly hilarious...

Comment: torsk in danish means harring(or idiot). Very funny..

Comment: Yes. The `false true` define is a win-win. You really should do that.

Comment: That switch statement will never hit the second case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define torsk break
```

but I also wonder why would you want such weird thing...

Comment: The OP replied. See the comments... :d

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with preprocessor

```
#define torsk break
```

you can do anything you want like

```
#define forever for(;;)
```